# Pesach Upcoming Events tags

Tags: discussion, tags, events

Our Upcoming Events sidebar has a link to Pesach questions, with the tags [passover](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover) and [passover-seder-hagada](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover-seder-hagada). Should it be expanded to include other Pesach-related tags?

I've stumbled upon:

[four-sons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-sons)
[marror-bitter-herbs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marror-bitter-herbs)
[matzah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matzah)
[gebrochts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gebrochts)
[kitniyos-semigrain-legume](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitniyos-semigrain-legume)
[chametz-leaven](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chametz-leaven)
[four-cups-wine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-cups-wine)

though there may very well be others I've missed.

Comment: One more that I missed before that might need to go on (too long?) - [tag:maseches-pesachim] @msh210

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good idea, thanks. I've changed the URL to include all the ones you mention except [four-sons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-sons). I've omitted one because including all of them would make the URL too long for the system to handle (in that context). I chose that one to omit because it (now) has only one question that doesn't have one of the other listed tags.